# echo variable before call function

Tags: php

First of all I should say this code is a sample and i remake for you to show what i want my original code too huge and can't post here, but the logic and functions similar to this example.

I made a dynamic title in a function called `getTitle()` and it show on `#side-bar` now i want to use this title in `h1` tag too, but as you see h1 tag rendered before this function, and i'm not able to move `h1` tag after `#side-bar`. Now i want to know how can i `echo` a variable that generated from a function, before call this function.

**PHP:**

```
<?php
function getTitle(){
global $title;
    // some code to generate dynamic title
    $title = "example title";

    echo $sample = "123";
    return $title;
    // other code
}
?>
```

**HTML:**

```
echo <h1><?=$title;?></h1>;
<div id="side-bar"><?php getTitle(); ?></div> <!-- call -->
```

*I know if i move `$title` after calling the function `getTitle();` it works fine but i need to echo `$title` before calling this function. **Is it possible?** or any idea, or logic to do this?*

*Also i know i can clone the title from side-bar to h1 with `javascript` or etc.. but this is a `h1` tag and can't fill it after page load in client side.*

Comment: you can create an array then return that and echo what you want to echo.
`$arr['title'] = "example title";  $arr['sample'] = 'sample';`

Comment: Don't do that. Straighten your logic out. **First gather the data. Then put the data into the view.** Interleaving the two stages just makes thing difficult to manage and causes you to tie yourself up in this kind of knot.

Comment: In your PHP example, when it hits that `return` its going to end that function. Nothing after the `return` will execute. But as @Quentin said... just try not to mix outputs like that, as its very hard to follow, debug, and control in the end.

Comment: what do you even mean? you want to do something like this: `$title = 'blabla'; echo $title; function getTitle(){..your code}`?

Comment: @IncredibleHat ah, you right, it is my mistake to write this example, the original code not like this.

Comment: @Quentin nice advise, i'll try this.

Comment: @Edwin I think I said clearly. Otherwise, others would not understand. No, Take a look again to my code please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP:

```
<?php
function getTitle(){
    // some code to generate dynamic title
    return ['title' => 'Example title', 'sample' => '123'];
}
?>
```

HTML:

```
$response=getTitle();
echo <h1><?=$response["sample"];?></h1>;
<div id="side-bar"><?php $response["title"]; ?></div> <!-- call -->
```

Comment: Why not just return an array?

Comment: True, thats a more efficient way. Been working on API's lately, making me think about json all the time xD

Comment: @Manikiran even with `JSON` creation, you can create an array with `$a = [];` instead of `$a = array();`

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is wrong. Instructions are not executed after return statement.

**PHP function**

```
<?php
    function getTitle(){
        $title = /*generate dynamic title*/;
        return $title;
    }
?>
```

**HTML**

```
 <?php $generatedTitle = getTitle(); ?>
 <h1><?php echo $generatedTitle; ?></h1>
 <div id="side-bar"><?php echo $generatedTitle; ?></div>
```